# Does Firebase for Unity contain childByAutoId?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a fairly experienced Firebase user and I'm recently working on a gaming project with Unity 2019. Does the **Unity** Firebase framework contain an equivalent to the in iOS/Web available `childByAutoId`?

```
public void UploadHighScore(Highscore highscore) {

    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(highscore);

    reference
      .Child("Highscores")
      .ChildByAutoID // does not exist
      .SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
}
```

Is there another best practice approach for getting a unique ID in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unity the method is called [`Push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/database-reference#push).

It's actually called `push()` on most platforms that Firebase supports, with iOS being an exception calling it `childByAutoId()`.

Comment: Thank you Frank. As always a perfect and fast answer. I appreciate the documentation reference.

Answer (score 0):

Frank answered my question correctly and also provided a documentation reference.
Following a code example in case anyone else comes up with this problem.

```
public void UploadHighScore(Highscore highscore) {

    DatabaseReference location = reference
     .Child("Highscores")
     .Push();

    highscore.uuid = location.Key; // storing the uuid for later usage like deletion etc
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(highscore);
    location.SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
    Debug.Log($"auto generated ID: {location.Key}"); // new child uuid
}
```